# How to create an HTTP view take takes longer than Heroku's timeout to process?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku, python-asyncio

So, I have a code like this, which is a simple timer with an interval inside it:

Timer:

```
async def timer_function(target_time_obj, remaining_timers, timer_ended_flag):
    target_time = dt.datetime.strptime(target_time_obj["target_time"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    time_accepted = target_time_obj['time_accepted']
    timer_id = target_time_obj["id"]
    fixture = target_time_obj["fixture_id"]
    bookmaker = target_time_obj["bookmaker"]
    tracked_odd = target_time_obj["tracked_odd"]
    initial_value = target_time_obj["initial_value"]

    time_difference = target_time - dt.datetime.now()
    timeout_seconds = max(time_difference.total_seconds(), 0)

    if timeout_seconds > 0:
        interval_task = asyncio.create_task(interval_printer(timer_id, fixture, bookmaker, tracked_odd, time_accepted, initial_value, timer_ended_flag))
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout_seconds)
        timer_ended_flag.set()
        remaining_timers.remove(target_time_obj)

        for odd in all_data:
            if odd['id'] == tracked_odd:
                current = all_data.pop(all_data.index(odd))
                await asyncio.to_thread(requests.post, f'{URL}/api/history',  json=json.dumps(current), headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {SECRET_API_KEY}'})

        await interval_task
```

Interval:

```
async def interval_printer(timer_id, fixture, bookmaker, tracked_odd, time_accepted, initial_value, timer_ended_flag):
    await fetch_and_update_data(fixture, bookmaker, tracked_odd, initial_value, time_accepted)

    while not timer_ended_flag.is_set():
        current_time = dt.datetime.now()
        # next_hour = (current_time + dt.timedelta(hours=1)).replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
        next_hour = (current_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=1)).replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
        time_difference = max(next_hour - current_time, dt.timedelta())

        await asyncio.sleep(time_difference.total_seconds())
        
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            result = await fetch_data_async(session, f"https://api.sportmonks.com/v3/football/odds/pre-match/fixtures/{fixture}?api_token={TOKEN}&filters=bookmakers:{bookmaker}&timezone={LOCAL_DATA['timezone']}")
            for odd in result['data']:
                if odd['id'] == tracked_odd:
                    for i in range(len(all_data)):
                        if all_data[i]['id'] == tracked_odd:
                            all_data[i]['statistic']['hours'].append(odd['value'])
```

Fetch And Update:

```
async def fetch_and_update_data(fixture, bookmaker, tracked_odd, initial_value, time_accepted):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        result = await fetch_data_async(session, f"https://api.sportmonks.com/v3/football/odds/pre-match/fixtures/{fixture}?api_token={TOKEN}&filters=bookmakers:{bookmaker}&timezone={LOCAL_DATA['timezone']}")
        for odd in result['data']:
            if odd['id'] == tracked_odd:
                current_fixture = await fetch_data_async(session, f"https://api.sportmonks.com/v3/football/fixtures/{fixture}?api_token={TOKEN}&timezone={LOCAL_DATA['timezone']}")
                res_odd = { some data }
                all_data.append(res_odd)
```

Track and fetch data sync(for time out)

```
async def fetch_data_async(session, url):
    async with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url, timeout=10) as response:
            return await response.json()
        
async def track(target_times):
    remaining_timers = target_times.copy()
    timer_ended_flags = [asyncio.Event() for _ in range(len(target_times))]

    timer_tasks = [timer_function(target_time_obj, remaining_timers, timer_ended_flag) for target_time_obj, timer_ended_flag in zip(target_times, timer_ended_flags)]
    
    await asyncio.gather(*timer_tasks)
    print(all_data)
    return jsonify(all_data)
```

So here is my endpoint:

```
@conf.app.route('/api/fixtures_data', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS', 'GET'], endpoint='fixtures_data')
@cross_origin()
@func.api_key_required_decorator
def fixtures_data():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        response = jsonify({'message': 'CORS preflight request successful'})
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
        return response
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        target_times = request.get_json()
        print(target_times)
        asyncio.run(func.track(target_times))
        print(jsonify(conf.all_data))
        return jsonify(conf.all_data)
    
    print(type(conf.all_data))
    return conf.all_data
```

On local host everything works perfectly, because there is no limitation for post request handling, but when trying to use this code on heroku it gives me this errors:

```
2023-10-02T09:50:58.191106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/fixtures_data" host= request_id=f32be5e3-7bd3-42d9-9d7b-7913e6b57600 fwd="78.26.236.11" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2023-10-02T09:50:59.096508+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-10-02 09:50:59 +0000] [2] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7)
2023-10-02T09:50:59.098039+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-10-02 09:50:59 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-10-02T09:50:59.252654+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-10-02 09:50:59 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

The problem generally is that app.route doesnt handle post request immediately, but only when the timer is out. Unfortunately, heroku timeout limit is 30 seconds.

But I need this app.route return me data from multiple timers using asyncio, because threads doesnt work at all.

Comment: I suggest you re-write the title for this question. It is a nice and well-formed question, but has sequences intended for formatting text in the title. Try to be specific about what you want. eg. "How to create an HTTP view take takes longer than Heroku's timeout to process?"

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Hope that it will help me!

Comment: Great. Now for the bad news: this just won't work with changes on the Python side - heroku simply won´t wait more than its set timeout before erroring.  If you have comparatively few of these requests, you could maybe rent a full VPS on another provider and redirect these requests there - this would allow you to keep the frontend architecture.
Other than that, you have to change to some kind of server sent events or websockets.